# codeigniter inserting data in 2 table with dynamically changing colums

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Hi frinds I have a post data coming like this

```
Array
(
    [m_categoryid] => 81
    [subcat_id_for_cat] => 87
    [title] => test
    [body] => test
    [adtype] => 2
    [1] => iphone
    [2] => xxx
    [7] => yes
    [submit] => Submit ads
```

where top 5 fields are fixed fields going to one table table_1 however the last 3 fields are dynamic fields which keeps on increasing or decreasing fields and goes to another table table_2

Can't figure out how to solve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

or if you can't modify array and dynamic data got always numeric key

```
$arr = array
(
    "m_categoryid" => "81",
    "0" => "iphone",
    "2" => "xxx",
    "submit" => "Submit ads"
);

foreach ($arr as $key=>$row)
{
    if(is_numeric($key))
    {
echo "insert table_2\n";
    } else {
echo "insert table_1\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try use multidimension array

```
Array
(
    [m_categoryid] => 81
    [subcat_id_for_cat] => 87
    [title] => test
    [body] => test
    [adtype] => 2
    [dynamic] => array(
       [1] => iphone
       [2] => xxx
       [7] => yes
    )
    [submit] => Submit ads
)
```

then

```
foreach($dynamic as $row)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create 2 array. In the first you put the first 5 elements, in the seconds the other. After you can assigne the right array at the table.

```
$input = Array (  
"m_categoryid" => 81,  
"subcat_id_for_cat" => 87,  
"title" => "test",  
"body" => "test",  
"adtype" => 2,  
"iphone" => 1,
"submit" => "Submit ads" 
);

$c = count($input); 
$length = $c - 5; 
$first = array_slice($input, 0, 5,true); 
$last = array_slice($input, 5,$length, true);
$headfirst = array();
$valuefirst = array(); 
foreach($first as $key => $value){
    $headfirst[] = $key;
    $valuefirst[] = $value;
}

$this->table->set_heading($headfirst);
$this->table->add_row($valuefirst);
echo $this->table->generate();

$last = array_slice($input, 5,$length, true);
$headlast = array();
$valuelast = array(); 
foreach($last as $key => $value){
    $headlast[] = $key;
    $valuelast[] = $value;
}
$this->table->set_heading($headlast);
$this->table->add_row($valuelast);
echo $this->table->generate();
```

That's all